# python, pandas, work through bad data

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

so I've got a very large dataframe of mostly floats (read from a csv) but every now and then, I get a string, or nan

```
                         date load
0  2016-07-12 19:04:31.604999    0
...
10 2016-07-12 19:04:31.634999    nan
...
50 2016-07-12 19:04:31.664999    ".942.197"
...
```

I can deal with nans (interpolate), but can't figure out how to use replace in order to catch strings, and not numbers

```
df.replace(to_replace='^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$',regex=True,value = float('nan'))
```

returns all nans.  I wan't nans for only when it's actually a string

Comment: Can you post an example of 'something weird'

Comment: the string is the only issue I'm having, removed "something weird" from my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `pandas.to_numeric`. It works with series-like data.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([0, float('nan'), '.942.197'], columns=['load'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
       load
0         0
1       NaN
2  .942.197

In [4]: pd.to_numeric(df['load'], errors='coerce')
Out[4]: 
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
Name: load, dtype: float64
```

Actually `to_numeric` will try to convert every item to numeric so if you have a string that looks like a number it will be converted:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame([0, float('nan'), '123.456'], columns=['load'])

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
      load
0        0
1      NaN
2  123.456

In [7]: pd.to_numeric(df['load'], errors='coerce')
Out[7]: 
0      0.000
1        NaN
2    123.456
Name: load, dtype: float64
```

I am not aware of any way to convert every non-numeric type to `nan`, other than iterate (or maybe use `apply`or `map`) and check for `isinstance`.

Comment: this resulted in a value of 992344 (just something huge, when I know my data are only between zero and one), so I had to followup with df = df[df<1]; thanks!

Comment: @user2539738 Yes, I skipped that part because your sample did not have any numeric strings. See edit. I don't know how to convert every string to `nan` in an elegant and efficient way, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that `.replace()` will only apply to *string* datatypes. If you apply it to a non-string datatype (e.g. your numeric types), it will return nan. Converting the entire frame/series to string before using replace would work around this, but probably isn't the "best" way of doing so (e.g. see @Goyo's answer)!

See the notes on [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) page.